# Why Disciplined badge?

Tags: support, badges

**[Disciplined](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/disciplined)** badge will be awarded to users who Deleted own post with score of 3 or higher.

Here I don't understand the purpose of this badge. If anyone has a post with score of 3 or higher, means it is somewhat useful and clear. So there is no need to delete their post. So what is the purpose of this badge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is that they delete their own answer because it is wrong, was written because a misunderstanding of the question, or it is not an appropriate answer, and they notice that; the fact they do it even if the answer score is 3 makes them [disciplined](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/disciplined#discipline_1__4).

Strictly speaking, an answer's score doesn't say anything about the its quality. In fact, the user who answered the question, and the users who voted the answer, could have misunderstood the question. If that were the case, the answer would be not helpful, even if it got three up-votes.

Comment: I think this badge is possible for the post without answer. I don't understand you 2nd paragraph, meaning author can delete the question only if that post is unanswered. Is there any alternate way to delete the post with answer- something like flagging to Mod!.

Comment: The badge is also for answers. In the second paragraph I am talking of somebody who answered a question he misunderstood; anybody can delete their answer, even if its score is higher than 2. The only limit is an accepted answer, which cannot be deleted by normal users.

Comment: I have this badge :-) for a deleted answer! The fact is that people here upvote and downvote on many different grounds. Not *all* DSE users (present company excepted of course) have sufficient knowledge to tell when an answer is right or wrong. I somehow managed to give an answer that was dead wrong. It still got upvoted. When I realized the error, I did of course delete it.